# Jenkins gives no file or directory when the repo is traversed after the SCM checkout

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Jenkins Version: 2.107.1
Issue: Although the file is present Jenkins is not able to access it or cd into the repo.

NOTE :  is replaced in the actual code with the actual github repo 
Pipeline code :
`

```
node {
   stage('Checkout SCM') {
       checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/*********']],    doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [], submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: '******', url: 'https://github.com/******']]])
   }
   stage('Copy the file from the Jenkins-script in the workspace and run it') {
       sh 'pwd'
       sh 'ls -lrt $WORKSPACE'
       sh 'ls -lrt $WORKSPACE/<repo>/jenkins_scripts/'
       sh 'bash $WORKSPACE/<repo>/jenkins_scripts/test-snapshot.sh'
   }
}
```

`
Console output :

```
`
[Pipeline] sh
[snap] Running shell script
+ ls -lrt /root/workspace/snap/<repo>/jenkins_scripts/
ls: cannot access '/root/workspace/snap/<repo>/jenkins_scripts/': No such file or directory
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 2
Finished: FAILURE
`
```

Comment: I hope someone answers this soon. I've hit the exact same problem. Unfortunately throwing the `chmod -R 777 ./` at it doesn't help. It shows that the permissions are all changed, but the "No such file or directory" keeps happening anyway.